# Strange Math 2.2

Tags: mathematics

I don't know why I even took this class. All the math is so complicated. We were learning order of operations and then I get this monstrosity. Can you help me do it?

$(3+4)(2-3)=18-1$
$(2-7)^2+(1-5)=-44-33$
$(5-1)(9+8)=53+31$
$(6-2)^2-(10-13)= \ ?$

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer is

> $22-11$

since the "complicated" math is in fact

> complex (kind of a synonym for *complicated*) number arithmetics with $i$'s omitted (one can easily guess that since all the numbers come in pairs, joined with plus or minus signs)

So far

> $(3+4i)(2-3i)=18-1i$
>  $(2-7i)^2+(1-5i)=-44-33i$
>  $(5-1i)(9+8i)=53+31i$
>  $(6-2i)^2-(10-13i)=22-11i$